# Div auto width, create animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I've got two divs next to eachother. When I toggle the one on the right, then one on the left is always set to auto width, so it takes up the space the other one left, and when I show the other one again it goes back to its space.

This solution is working great for me, the only problem is I can't trigger a transition animation this way, and I'm looking for a solution everywhere and I can't find it.

Is it even possible to trigger an animation on this auto change width?

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Although it is `height` instead of `width`, this may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3508605/691711